# Java cannot create a file - Linux

Tags: java, file-io, makefile, ioexception, bufferedwriter

When I create a file in Ubuntu using a Java program I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at actions.create.actionPerformed(create.java:18)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and obviously the file is not created, even tried running it as root but still nothing. Here is my code:

```
    File shortcut;
    shortcut = new File(global.location + "/" + global.name + ".desktop");

    try {
    FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter(shortcut.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bWrite = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);
    shortcut.createNewFile();

    bWrite.write("[Desktop Entry]\nType=" + global.type + "\nTerminal=" + global.term + "\nIcon=" + global.icon + "\nExec=" + global.exec + "\nName=" + global.name);
    bWrite.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {}
```

Can someone please help with this problem? Ive always had this problem when creating files using java.

Comment: Where are you declaring global?

Comment: u sure u have the permission to create the file in directory? check what it returns ? true or falsE?

Comment: Just a remark, your class name should start with a capital letter: `Create.java`. Also see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: This is a gui program, global is the class that contains all the global variables. and capitalizing the classes really wont make a difference to my problem.

Comment: also, the global.type/term/icon/exec/name get the text of a textfield. so global.location gets the dir of the file to be created in, say: /home/user/Desktop and the global.name which is getting the name that you name the shortcut that the user inputs in a textfield so it would be, /home/user/Desktop/name.desktop

Comment: What is line 18 of create.java?

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
System.out.println(shortcut.getAbsoluteFile());
```

and double check if the directory really exists. I have a feeling, `shortcut.createNewFile();` throws the NPE because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the File creator where you enter the parent Folder and the filename:

```
File subFolder=new File(folderName,subFolder);
File f=new File(folderName,filename;)
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); //this to see the actual path of the file
subFolder.mkdirs();
BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you the truth, I don't know what you did here, It seems like you were poking in the dark trying to make a file. I want to show you a class (which I created) that might be able to help you with this:

```
package your.package;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileHelper
{
    public static boolean createFile(String dir)
{
    return FileHelper.createFile(dir, false);
}

public static boolean createFile(String dir, boolean isDirectory)
{
    boolean returning = false;
    boolean created = false;

    Path p = Paths.get(dir);
    try
    {
        if (Files.exists(p))
        {
            returning = true;
        }
        else if (isDirectory)
        {
            Files.createDirectory(p);
            created = true;
            returning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Files.createFile(p);
            created = true;
            returning = true;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (returning)
    {
        Util.println((created ? "Created New " : "") + (isDirectory ? "Directory" : "File") + (created ? "" : " Already Exists") + " In: " + p.toString());
    }
    return returning;
}

public static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, String stuff)
{
    return FileHelper.writeToFile(fileName, stuff, true);
}

public static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, String stuff, boolean newLine)
{
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true)))
    {
        writer.write(stuff);
        if (newLine) writer.newLine();
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException x)
    {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        x.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static BufferedReader getFileReader(String fileName)
{
    Charset c = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    Path p = Paths.get(fileName);

    try
    {
        return Files.newBufferedReader(p, c);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean deleteDirectory(File dir)
{
    Util.requireNonNull(dir);

    if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\"dir\" Must exist!");
    }

    String[] files = dir.list();

    for (int i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        File f = new File(dir, files[i]);

        if (f.isDirectory())
        {
            deleteDirectory(f);
            Util.println("Found new directory to delete: " + f.getPath() + " Deleting now...");
        }
        else
        {
            f.delete();
            Util.println("Deleted File: " + f.getPath());
        }
    }
    Util.println("Deleted Directory: " + dir.getPath());
    return dir.delete();
}
}
```

Let me know if this helps your problem! By the way, you don't need to give me any credit for this file. Its the publics now! Good Luck and Happy Coding!